# Async Function with Promise.All Only Running After Updating Code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, async-await, es6-promise

I'm writing an asynchronous function in React that should set the "coords" state to an array of objects containing US states and their respective latitudes/longitudes. To do this, I'm making an API call and resolving those calls using Promise.all. On the first refresh of the page, the function works as intended. However, on subsequent refreshes, the function does not execute the Promise.all statement and therefore does not set the coords state. Why is this the case and how can I resolve this issue?

```
export default function App() {

  const [covidDataJSON, setCovidDataJSON] = useState(null);
  const [stateNames, setStateNames] = useState([]);
  const [coords, setCoords] = useState([]);
  const [stateInfos, setStateInfos] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchCoords();
  }, [])

  const fetchCoords = async () => {
    try {
      getStateNames();
      const req = await Promise.all(stateNames.map(async (state) => {
        return await axios.get(`https://nominatim.geocoding.ai/search.php?state=${state}&format=jsonv2`);
      }))
      for (let i = 0; i < req.length; i++){
        const stateInfo = req[i].data[0];
        if (req[i].data.length !== 0)
          setCoords(coordsArr => [...coordsArr, {name: stateInfo.display_name, lat: stateInfo.lat, lon: stateInfo.lon}]);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  };

  const getStateNames = () => {
    try {
      const stateArr = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < states.length; i++){
        stateArr.push(states[i].name);
      }
      setStateNames(stateArr);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
```

Comment: When you say "refresh", do you mean a browser refresh (like you're reloading the page itself)?

Comment: Yes, I mean like a full page reload.

Comment: Are the requests going through (i.e. in the Chrome dev tools Network tab)? Are you getting rate-limited?

Comment: It's not clear where `states` is coming from. Is it actually the same after your "refresh"? Also, the `getStateNames()` call [is not going to update the `const stateName`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54069253/1048572), so `stateNames` is always the empty array when your effect runs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your promise.all does not execute because stateNames is still an empty array.

You need to define 2 useEffect hooks as follows. -

```
// this will trigger function fetchCoords once your have set the stateNames.
useEffect(() => {
    if(!stateNames || !stateNames.length){
        return;
    }
    fetchCoords();
}, [stateNames]);

// this hook will set your stateNames once the component loads.
useEffect(() => {
    getStateNames();
}, [])
```

Also, I don't see the states variables used in getStateNames defined in above sample code. Also remove getStateNames() call from inside of fetchCoords() Let me know if the above works for you and try logging stateNames to verify this.

Comment: The `fetchCoords` will run twice. Once on mount, and once when `stateNames` is set.

Comment: Good Point! we may just need skip the initial load. I guess checking the length of stateNames array should be enough to skip it.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli Shouldn't matter - `fetchCoords` does nothing when `stateNames` is empty

Comment: This ended up resolving the issue. Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

1. Inside `getStateNames()`, you're calling `setStateNames(stateArr);` setter function for a state is async. You're mapping over stateNames inside `fetchCoords()`. There is a possibility that `stateNames`state is not updated when map loop is run. Thats why I return `stateArr` from `getStateNames()` and use that value inside `fetchCoords()`.
2. Inside `fetchCoords()`, you've added the following code

```
const req = await Promise.all(stateNames.map(async (state) => {
        return await axios.get(`https://nominatim.geocoding.ai/search.php?state=${state}&format=jsonv2`);
      }))
```

There is no need to `await axios.get()` here because you're already using `Promise.all` to await for promises to resolve, that's why I've removed `await axios.get()` from `.map` and simply returning an array of promises for `Promise.all()`

Give this a try. I think this should work.

```
export default function App() {
  const [covidDataJSON, setCovidDataJSON] = useState(null);
  const [stateNames, setStateNames] = useState([]);
  const [coords, setCoords] = useState([]);
  const [stateInfos, setStateInfos] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchCoords();
  }, []);

  const fetchCoords = async () => {
    try {
      const stateArr = getStateNames();
      const req = await Promise.all(
        stateArr.map((state) => {
          return axios.get(
            `https://nominatim.geocoding.ai/search.php?state=${state}&format=jsonv2`
          );
        })
      );

      for (let i = 0; i < req.length; i++) {
        const stateInfo = req[i].data[0];
        if (req[i].data.length !== 0)
          setCoords((coordsArr) => [
            ...coordsArr,
            {
              name: stateInfo.display_name,
              lat: stateInfo.lat,
              lon: stateInfo.lon
            }
          ]);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  };

  const getStateNames = () => {
    try {
      const stateArr = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < states.length; i++) {
        stateArr.push(states[i].name);
      }
      setStateNames(stateArr);
      return stateArr;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: What did you change, and *why* do you think that solves the problem?

Comment: @Bergi added the changes which were made